# Bootstrap 3 thumbnail shows content on hover, but it covers the parent div also

Tags: jquery, html

I create some `<divs>` with the thumbnail class. I would like the captions to appear when the mouse is hovered over the image only. I have done this so far, however it ends up covering the whole div.

How can I only get the caption to slide in only over the image?

```js
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(1000); //.fadeIn(250)
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(300); //.fadeOut(205)
});
```

```css
.thumbnail .caption.caption-slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <!--Bear-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <h3>Bear</h3>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption caption-slide">
          <p>BEAR BEAR BEAR SALMON</p>
        </div>
        <img src="http://www.placebear.com/700/500" alt="Government">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--bEAR-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption caption-slide">
          <p>FDSFASDFADFADFA.</p>
        </div>
        <img src="http://www.placebear.com/700/500" alt="Government">
        <h3>bEAR2</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is my [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLdKdX).
EDIT:(Example is updated. Left the second image as original to show what the issue was)

Comment: you can play with top, left, width and height properties of .thumbnail .caption.caption-slide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add  wrap your image and caption into div('img-wrapper') and give `position: relative;` to the wrapper div('img-wrapper')

```js
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(1000); //.fadeIn(250)
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(300); //.fadeOut(205)
});
```

```css
.thumbnail .caption.caption-slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrapper img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <!--Bear-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <h3>Bear</h3>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
          <div class="caption caption-slide">
            <p>BEAR BEAR BEAR SALMON</p>
          </div>
          <img src="http://www.placebear.com/700/500" alt="Government">
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--bEAR-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
          <div class="caption caption-slide">
            <p>FDSFASDFADFADFA.</p>
          </div>
          <img src="http://www.placebear.com/700/500" alt="Government">
        </div>
        <h3>bEAR2</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```